# What are the parameters sending to app.initialize() in phonegap

Tags: cordova

When we start a phonegap project, there is this function app.initialize(), which will set up listeners and other stuff in one var declaration as the following:

```
var app = {(...),(...),(...)}
```

But should we include all functions we need in this one variable declaration? What exactly should this variable contain.

I have checked on google, phonegap api docs. None of them have a good explanation( I do not think phonegap docs ever explained this.

**EDIT**:
In response to @Dawson Loudon, I thought the number of functions initialized should be determined by user. But in one scenario, I added an extra function right after receivedEvent(one of the defaults), the program simply failed. When it runs on my Nexus tablet, it says "xxx has unexpectedly stopped". Then  I am confused if app.initialize() really only invokes initialize() and the functions mentioned in the initialize() and the dependent functions it is containing.

Comment: It's up to you. The default app object and app.initialize function are just there for an example or a starting point. You can configure your JS anyway you would like.

Comment: I have added a scenario to explain my confusion. I know there are other ways but I still want to understand how app.intialize() works in the latest phonegap build. Hopefully it helps. I prefer to give a short line of code to demonstrate how var app={} should look like.